# Realitykit: how to modify/rig a 3D model?

Tags: ios, 3d, blender, realitykit, usdz

I have bought a 3D model in Blender format about a clock with a button for my iOS app with RealityKit. I could convert the model into USD format (to use with RealityKit) then load, display, resize, rotate the model to the right position in my app as I need. Now, I need to switch the button of the model to positions on or off, then rotate animatedly clock handles to their right positions. I have looked into the exported model (for iOS, in USD format) but can’t find any name, part about the button and handles to modify them.

I’m so confused what to do next. Could I modify the model in Blender thus I could have something related to button, handles (in exported USD model) to twist them later? Should I add animations to the model to do that task? I’m worried if I could control handles for correct positions with animations. Or should I break the model into several sub-models, say one for the button, two for handles and one for clock body then set manually their positions to show them all together?